# activate UIPath licence trial

Tags: uipath

I'me newer in UIPath, I just finish to install it and l would like to start trial.
l use the manual activation because automatic activation is blocked by the proxy.
However l always have this error when l try to activate it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9T27N.png)

Comment: I ended up uninstalling it because of this exact problem. Moving to a different product. Don't have the time to wrap my head around license activation for a community edition.

Answer (score 1):

What os image version you have?
Because if you are using  image version not supported by uipath libraries then it creates such errors.

For example i was using windows 7 image version less then 4.2 so i was also getting same error but after reinstalling new image having version greater then and equal to 4.2 then now it is working good.